# Convert a shiny "tags$" in HTML()

Tags: html, r, shiny, shinydashboard

I would like to write this code (that works):

```
  tags$li(
    class = "dropdown",
    tags$a(
      height = 40, href = "https://www.google.com.br",
      title = "Whatsapp", target = "_blank",
      tags$strong(
        icon("whatsapp"), ""
      )
    )
  )
```

in the `HTML()` form. I tried:

```
HTML(
"<li class='dropdown'>
<a href='https://www.google.com.br' target='_blank'>Whatsapp</a>
<strong class='fas fa-whatsapp'></strong>
</li>"
)
```

and this code:

```
  HTML(
    '<li class="dropdown">
      <a style="height:40px" href="https://www.google.com.br" 
title="Whatsapp" target="_blank">
      <strong>
      <i class="fas fa-whatsapp"></i>
      </strong>
      </a>
      </li>'
  )
```

But an error appear:

> An error has occurred!

> Expected an object with class 'shiny.tag'.

My app:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

header <- dashboardHeader(

  title = "Dashboard", 
  titleWidth = 300, 

  HTML(
  "<li class='dropdown'>
  <a https://www.google.com.br' target='_blank'>Whatsapp</a>
  <strong class='fas fa-whatsapp'></strong>
  </li>"
  )

)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(

  width = 300

)

body <- dashboardBody(

  uiOutput(
    outputId = "hour"
  )

)

ui <- dashboardPage(

  header = header, 
  sidebar = sidebar, 
  body = body

)

server <- function(input, output) {



}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I would just like to do this transformation to better edit my `HTML` document. I need to do this with just `HTML()`.

How to solve this? I made two attempts, as I showed, but I couldn't solve it.

Comment: What is it you can't modify using htmltools's `tag` function? I wouldn't recommend going this path. Please see this [related chapter](https://unleash-shiny.rinterface.com/htmltools-overview.html#alternative-way-to-write-tags) from *Outstanding User Interfaces with Shiny*.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I understood and will read this document you sent me better. But out of curiosity, how would I adjust this code with `HTML()`? It's possible?

Answer (score 0):

Placing the HTML() content inside `tags$li()` with `'dropdown'` class works

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

header <- dashboardHeader(

  title = "Dashboard", 
  titleWidth = 300,
  tags$li(
    class = "dropdown",
    HTML("
      <a https://www.google.com.br' target='_blank'>Whatsapp</a>
      <strong class='fas fa-whatsapp'></strong>
    ")
  )
)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  width = 300
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  uiOutput(
    outputId = "hour"
  )
)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  header = header, 
  sidebar = sidebar, 
  body = body
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```